# NSDictionary objectForKey - need an NSArray with one element instead of just the element

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I'm new to objective-c and need some help. In the code below, if the xml contains only one element, then the objectForKey calls will result in a single element instead of an NSArray with one element. How should I update the code to make sure that the line:

```
[[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] setTags:[[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST] objectForKey:XML_OPTION]];
```

always calls setTags with an NSArray (even if the xml contains zero or one element)?

```
NSString *XMLResponse = [request responseString];
NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:XMLResponse error:&parseError];
NSDictionary *result = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:XML_RESULT];

if ([[[result objectForKey:XML_ERROR_CODE] objectForKey:XML_TEXT] isEqualToString:XML_ERROR_NONE]) {
    [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] setTags:[[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST] objectForKey:XML_OPTION]];
    [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] save];
}
```

The xml OPTION_LIST element contains one or more OPTION element. It's when there is only one OPTION element that the error occur (outside the scope of this code).
I appreciate your help.

Comment: you can test the object for being kind of particular class. Here you would test : `[myObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` which will tell you if you got an array. One question, what are you getting if the XML contains zero element ?

Comment: Good question! I know, I need to include a check for zero elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you try to send `objectForKey:` message to some object that isn't an `NSDictionary` instance.

You would include a test to detect that and pass the `setTags:` method that element directly according to the test result.

```
if([[[result objectForKey:XML_ERROR_CODE] objectForKey:XML_TEXT] isEqualToString:XML_ERROR_NONE]) {
    if([[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] setTags:[[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST] objectForKey:XML_OPTION]];
    }
    else {
        [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] setTags:[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST]];
    }
    [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] save];
}
```

Comment: The thing is that this bit: [[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST] objectForKey:XML_OPTION]] seem to return either an NSArray which is the expected, or a single element (of some type, I'm not sure which). In the debugger, if XML_OPTION_LIST contains several OPTION tags i get:po [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] activityCategories] 
<__NSArrayM 0x6eda050>(
{
    DELETABLE =     { ...... 
which is the correct. If there is just one OPTION tag in the OPTION_LIST element, then in debug mode i get:po [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] activityCategories] 
{
    DELETABLE =     {
        ....

Comment: it is not possible that you have an array, you can't send `objectForKey:` to an array. If it's the case use `objectAtIndex:` instead and test against `[NSArray class]`

Comment: I meant, it is not possible to send `objectForKey:` to an array, not that it is not possible that you got an array...

Comment: I found a similar question here:

NSDictionary objectForKey return value

And solved it like this: if ([[[result objectForKey:XML_ERROR_CODE] objectForKey:XML_TEXT] isEqualToString:XML_ERROR_NONE]) { NSArray *myarr = [[result objectForKey:XML_OPTION_LIST] objectForKey:XML_OPTION]; if (![myarr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { myarr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myarr]; } [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] setActivityLevels:myarr]; [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance] save];

}

Comment: exactly what I wrote...except that there, the author wraps the object in an array before passing it to themethod. Is the `setTags:` method supposed to have an array as argument ? if so, you should consider doing the same.